# keep terminal from clearing when closing an ssh session

Tags: ssh, terminal

When I exit an ssh session on some hosts, my terminal will clear. I would like it if this would never happen, is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally it shouldn't. If it does for you, then perhaps you have something in the `.bash_logout` or similar, on the box you have shelled into, that causes the shell on the server to clear the terminal when you log out.

Comment: `rm .bash_logout` did the trick (it had only the line `/usr/bin/clear`). That _was_ easy.